# How to integrate AutoCompleteBinding From ControlsFX to Javafx 19 project build with Maven

Tags: maven, javafx, controlsfx, maven-dependency

I am running into an error with my Javafx project where the AutoCompleteBinding class cannot be accessed because it does not export. I have found a lot of potential answers for this, but none of the solutions have worked.

I know this exact question was asked before (although it was for Javafx 14), and I have tried his solution. It did not work for me. I am using clean javafx:run goal for my run configuration.

Error Code

```
WARNING: Unknown module: org.controlsfx.controls specified to --add-exports
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml@19/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1857)
    at javafx.fxml@19/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1724)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base@19/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics@19/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8923)
    at javafx.controls@19/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:203)
    at javafx.controls@19/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:207)
    at javafx.controls@19/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base@19/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics@19/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3894)
    at javafx.graphics@19/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1887)
    at javafx.graphics@19/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2620)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:411)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:301)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:450)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:449)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:551)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml@19/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:84)
    at javafx.fxml@19/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1852)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.controlsfx.control.textfield.AutoCompletionBinding (in unnamed module @0x1b837739) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager (in module javafx.base) because module javafx.base does not export com.sun.javafx.event to unnamed module @0x1b837739
    at org.controlsfx.control.textfield.AutoCompletionBinding.<init>(AutoCompletionBinding.java:538)
    at impl.org.controlsfx.autocompletion.AutoCompletionTextFieldBinding.<init>(AutoCompletionTextFieldBinding.java:107)
    at impl.org.controlsfx.autocompletion.AutoCompletionTextFieldBinding.<init>(AutoCompletionTextFieldBinding.java:92)
    at org.controlsfx.control.textfield.TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(TextFields.java:188)
    at org.openjfx.delzerfxapp.RouteSheetController.setSearch(RouteSheetController.java:649)
    at org.openjfx.delzerfxapp.RouteSheetController.initialize(RouteSheetController.java:179)
    at javafx.fxml@19/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2655)
    at javafx.fxml@19/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    at javafx.fxml@19/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2516)
    at org.openjfx.delzerfxapp.HubController.openTab(HubController.java:158)
    at org.openjfx.delzerfxapp.HubController.rsBtnHandler(HubController.java:79)
    ... 57 more
```

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>delzerfxapp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
            <artifactId>javase</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
            <version>11.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
            <version>11-ea+24</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.32</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running -->
                        <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <options>
                                <option>--add-exports</option>
                                <option>javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event=org.controlsfx.controls</option>
                            </options>
                            <mainClass>org.openjfx.delzerfxapp.App</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I am entirely lost. The only answers that I could find on Stack Overflow are not working. I have added `--add-exports=javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event=org.controlsfx.controls` to my VM args.

Above in my pom.xml file you will see that I have the options in there.

Comment: From the ControlsFX doc: *“some of the controls had to depend on ugly hacks to make sure they work as they used to prior to JDK 9”*,  [like this](https://github.com/controlsfx/controlsfx/wiki/Using-ControlsFX-with-JDK-9-and-above#autocompletionbinding) for the `AutoCompletionBinding`.  Refer to the linked doc and duplicate for more info.

Comment: I have tried this. It is still not working for me @jewelsea

Comment: I don't really have any other meaningful suggestions.  The accepted answer in the duplicate should work as far as I can tell.  All JavaFX software should be the same version and not ea versions.   You could upgrade javafx-swing to 19, plugin to 0.0.8, JDK to 19, create an [mcve] which only uses controlsfx and the autocomplete binding and nothing else with no dependent libs, and is a modular project with a module-info and has the module specified in the mainClass section.  I don't know that any of those would fix your issue though.

Comment: If this question is not a duplicate of the linked question, please explain why in the comments. You can add an update in the question about how your case is different, but be specific please - if your reasoning is that the other answer "didn't work" then that does not shed any additional light on what problem you are having.

Comment: The weird thing about your error log is the message `WARNING: Unknown module: org.controlsfx.controls specified to --add-exports`.  This means that the module `org.controlsfx.controls` is not recognized.  Yet you clearly have the modular version of controlsfx as a dependency.  So, that means that this dependency is on the classpath, not the module path (I don't know why).  It needs to be on the module path.  Try running from the command line without the javafx maven plugin, placing controlsfx and javafx on the module path (as specificated in documentation at openjfx.io).

Comment: Alternately, if you do run controlsfx from the classpath rather than the module path, then open to ALL-UNNAMED: `--add-exports javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event=ALL-UNNAMED`, because that opens the package to everything on the classpath.

Comment: @halfer sorry for not explaining further. I am not entirely sure why my case was different than the question linked above, but I found out how my question was different than this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62626358/how-to-integrate-autocompletionbinding-from-controlsfx-in-a-modular-javafx-14-pr) which also became the solution. I did not have a module-info. After adding that and adding `requires org.controlsfx.controls` to it my code is working. Thank you @jewelsea for your help.

Comment: No worries, it's fine. Just bear in mind that if one cannot explain why a new question is different to an existing one, it probably isn't possible to claim that they are different. It is a frequent event here that something that is categorically claimed as "not a duplicate" turns out to a perfect fit when some additional explanation is given.